# Queryable with generic Type <T> Handling Null or 0 Values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

> {"The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."}

I am trying to handle `null` values in a Queryable List with Generic Type `T`. I have tried `DefaultIfEmpty(0)` does not work because cannot convert Type T to int. How do I handle `null`s or `int`s To a list?

```
public  IEnumerable<T> SelectAll<T>(Object TableName)where T:class
{
    String TableNameString = Type.GetType(TableName.ToString()).Name;
            QueryString = "SELECT" + " " + "*" + " " + "FROM" + " " + TableNameString;
    if (Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        Database.Connection.Open();

    var a = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
    var t = a.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>(QueryString).AsQueryable().DefaultIfEmpty().ToList();
    List<T> newList = t;
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this method? What is the value of `T` in your specific case? is it `int`?

Comment: Is the column in the database nullable?

Comment: There are some null columns in the database @YacoubMassad

Comment: I am calling this method within a class which converts the Type of the Class to T and returns a Listof<classtype> @YacoubMassad

Comment: If the database table allows nulls in the table, you need to handle that appropriately in the code. You could do this using some SQL in your QueryString. `SELECT (prop1, prop2, prop3, ISNULL(prop4, 0), ISNULL(prop5, 'NULL') FROM table_name`; where prop4 is an integer type and prop5 is a varchar type. Also, you could put the current query in a single string, `QueryString = "SELECT * FROM " + TableNameString;`

Comment: @Ingenioushax I am trying to do a Select* on the required table so this wont achieve. unless I can handle nulls with the select *

Comment: @MarkEvans, that is a select statement.

Comment: How would I acheive that with a select *? @Ingenioushax

Comment: @MarkEvans, You can't. You need to explicitly list out all the properties.

Comment: @Ingenioushax I need a solution that will handle the checking at run-time

Comment: That is a solution for run-time. You just need to change your query string to include all the column names instead of *. `*` gets expanded by SQL to include all the column names as `*` simply means nothing unless it's interpreted, it's just shorthand for, "I need all this stuff, and I don't want to type out all the stuff I need so give it all to me"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (It) does not work because cannot convert Type T to int

It sounds like you need to pass in the type `int?` but the compiler will not allow it because of the generic parameter constraint. Can you remove this constraint from your method?

```
where T : class
```

I don't believe `DefaultIfEmpty(0)` does what you think it does. For one, it won't take effect until after the failed mapping to type `T`. Secondly, it doesn't replace `null` elements with `0`. It replaces an empty result set with a result set with exactly one item valued `0`.

Here is an example of nullable mappings and how DefaultIfEmpty works.

```
private void MappingExample()
{
    var complex = GetQuery<ComplexObject>("select Id, null as OptionalAlias from customer").ToArray();
    var simple = GetQuery<int?>("select null as OptionalAlias from customer").ToArray();
}

private void DefaultIfEmptyExample()
{
    var nulls = new int?[] { null, null };
    var nullsWithDefault = simple.DefaultIfEmpty(0); //still full of nulls

    var empty = new int?[] { };
    var emptyWithDefault = empty.DefaultIfEmpty(0); //has one item valued 0
}

private class ComplexObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? OptionalAlias { get; set; }
}

private IEnumerable<T> GetQuery<T>(string sql)
{
    var context = ContextManager.GetNew(); //proprietary, replace with your own
    var parms = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] { };
    return context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql, parms);
}
```